# My UTF-8 characters become unrecognised after passing with AJAX

Tags: encoding

I query names out of my UTF-8 database, if I echo them with php, they print just fine in a browser.

When I send them back however with Ajax, they become unrecognisable. After hours of debugging, I can't find my mistake.

This is the ajax code:

```
                    load: function(query, callback) {
                    if (!query.length) return callback();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'getnames.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                        data: {
                            name: selected_race.concat("__".concat(query)),
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            callback();
                        },
                        success: function(res) {
                            callback(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

And this is the get names.php

```
<?php
// parameters from URL
$type_entry = $_GET['name'];
$split = explode("__",$type_entry);
$race = "Race_".$split[0];
$name = "%".$split[1]."%";

// connect to the database and get the names
require 'connect_sql.php';

//$names_query = "Select Name FROM " .$race ." WHERE Name Like " .$name;
$names_query = "Select Name FROM ".$race." WHERE Name LIKE '".$name."'";

$query_result = mysqli_query($db, $names_query) or die("Zit hier de fout".mysql_error());;

$names = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){
    $names[] = "{ \"Name\": \"$row[0]\" }";

}

//output to browers
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
echo "[\n" .join(",\n", $names) ."\n]";?>
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `connect_sql.php` sets up the connection as UTF-8?

Comment: Ok, I added $db->set_charset("utf8") to the connect_sql.php and it worked. But how come that I could echo correctly a string with php?

Comment: And what is also strange, is that var_dump of the array prints the special characters not correct

Comment: Did the page you tested with `echo` and with `var_dump` actually specify the character set as UTF-8? Or did it fall back to the default (which is probably the character set your MySQL instance defaults to - something like ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Well even after changing the MySQL connection to UTF-8, the strings are not correctly echoed just with var_dump